# Trying to output a "Most visited blogs" list in wordpress multisite

Tags: plugins, functions, multisite, widgets

Does anyone know how to get a "most visited" list out of Wordpress Multisite?

I got alot of bloggers and have been looking for a way to output a top 10/20 list of most visited blogs, but cant find any plugin or snippets for this.

Example - like the list on the right side of this site (not WP) http://blogg.se/

Comment: But how are you measuring that? Any internal statistics?

Comment: I got Google analytics. Maybe thats a way to do it? I@m a bit short of knowlage here so thats why I'm asking here :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've found a very nice post, [Using the Google Analytics API in WordPress](http://theme.fm/2011/10/using-the-google-analytics-api-in-wordpress-2644/). It's a full blown tutorial and signed by a core contributor, no less.

> In this post we’ll talk about the API, authentication and firing requests to the API using the WordPress HTTP methods, about understanding and parsing the response and finally, we’ll go through some examples of how the techniques can be used to get interesting information from your Analytics account straight into your WordPress site.

---

The plugin [GD Press Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-press-tools/) has internal statistics, if you want to keep everything inside your environment.

And Jetpack statistics can be [queried](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70331/12615).